# "turning point" in a physical road

Tags: vocabulary

I guess it's not clear to use "turning point" to refer to the area pointed out by the red circle in the image below,

[image]

because ["turning point"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turning-point) means "the time at which a situation starts to change in an important way" while the one in question is a physical area.

What is the correct the word/phrase to refer to that area?

Comment: Those are called hairpin turns (US) and switchback turns (UK), They are not called turning points.

Comment: Note that using "turning point" in this context would still be understood as "the point at which you turn your vehicle." Rather than being a phrase, it's simply the normal syntactical combination of two separate words. Like any word with multiple meanings, context determines the meaning, not the spelling itself.

Comment: I (UK) call them _hairpin bends_.